# how to remove an element from .html() string?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I am trying to remove few elements from .html() and get a fresh set of elements.I am trying .remove() to delete the elements, but, its not helping me. Can you please help me in this regard ?

Adding the code below with the fiddle link.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/g7kptrac/

Answer (score 2):

this is because `$(dom).find(".hide")`doesn't  exists anymore as `$("#wrapper").html()` return all child element it will return `0` elements. you can try this:-

```
var dom = $("#wrapper").html();
 $("#newList").html(dom);
 $("#newList").find(".hide").each(function(){
 $(this).remove();
});
```

or simple:-

`$("#newList").find(".hide").remove()`

[Demo](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g7kptrac/1/)

Comment: thanks for your response.. i am looking at updating 'dom' variable with out updating the html DOM.

Comment: well you can wrap all html into div like this https://fiddle.jshell.net/g7kptrac/2/ other than you can't do much with that

Comment: @freshtoUI glad if that help you happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, you could do this:

```
$('cssSelector').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("#wrapper").find(".hide").each(function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```